# Regex to check the existence of a string in another string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to see the existence of `/target-` in a string of `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/../dir7/dir8/dir9/target-.a-word1-word2-alphanumberic1-alphanumberic2.md`).

```
$re = '/^(.*?)(\/target-)(.*?)(\.md)$/i';
$str = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/../dir7/dir8/dir9/target-.a-word1-word2-alphanumberic1-alphanumberic2.md';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Saxk8x/1

Do I use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` or are there faster or easier ways to do so?

Both `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` return null, even though Demo functions properly.

Comment: Have you tried just with [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)?

Comment: Sounds like this question is better suited on code review.

Comment: You use capture groups in the regex as if you need to capture the path, target and file name. Is that correct? Is `target` static or can it be `Target` and other variations also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to find the exact string `/target-`, you can use `strpos()` (`stripos()` if you want a case-insensitive search). It will be faster than the best regex.

```
$pos = strpos($str, '/target-');
if ($pos !== false) {
    var_dump($pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `stripos` and `strpos` is faster than regular expression, Here is simple working RegEx demo.

Snippet

```
$re = '/\/target\-/';
$str = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/../dir7/dir8/dir9/target-.a-word1-word2-alphanumberic1-alphanumberic2.md';

if(preg_match($re, $str, $match)){
echo $match[0].' found';
}else{
echo 'Aww.. No match found';
}
```

Check demo [here](https://3v4l.org/V09ud)

Note: If you want check only one occurance it's better to use `preg_match` rather than `preg_match_all` .

Read more about [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)